# print Mat float

Tags: c++, opencv

I am calculating the gradient of grayscale images using OpenCV, the resulting values for some pixels are negative (but i am unable to print them on screen).

**my Code:**

```
Mat gradX, kernelX, gray;
//i load an rgb image and convert it to grayscale here
gray.create(rows,cols,CV_32FC1);
kernelX = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << -1, 0, 1); 
gradX.create(rows,cols,CV_32FC1);
filter2D(gray,gradX,-1, kernelX,cvPoint(-1, -1),0);
```

I have tried these 2 methods to print the values of 5x5 top left corner of gradX

**Method 1** (it prints all values very small (e.g. 1.23e-40  . etc)):

```
for (int j=0; j<5;j++)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
    { 
        cout<< (float)gradX.at<float>(j, i) << " "; 
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

**Method 2** (it prints positive values fine, but all negative values are displayed as "0"):

```
for (int j=0; j<5;j++)
{
    uchar* data=gradX.ptr<uchar>(j);
    for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
    { 
        cout<< (float)data[i] << " "; 
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the mat with known values and skipping the calculation. That allows you to check if your printing code or filter2d code is wrong

Comment: Thanks, I tested it with known values and it seemed to work I will look into filter2d (its OpenCV's function), and check why it returns so low values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you

```
cout << gradX << endl;
```

?

Comment: i get this error "no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << gradX’"

Answer (score 1):

regarding method 2, something looks weird to me over there,
change it to be:

```
for (int j=0; j<5;j++)
{
    float* data=gradX.ptr<float>(j);
    for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
    { 
        cout<< data[i] << " "; 
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

you're accessing the i-th char (byte) in an array of floats (4-bytes) instead of accessing the i-th float (you're doing (start + i * byte) and you need (start + i * 4 * byte))